# Populating a Column in a Relation Using SQL Update Table and Set Commands in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access-2016

I am using MS Access 2016 to learn SQL as part of a class on the fundamentals of databases. I am tasked with adding a new column to a table and then populating that column. The column should reveal whether an account is paid in full or if a balance remains to be paid. Based on that criteria it contains only 'Yes' or 'No.' The formula relies on data from two tables (ENROLLMENT and COURSE).
[Here are the tables I created:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km8Vf.png)

I have been researching the problem here and on other sites but not finding the logic and only getting syntax errors.
[Here are a couple ways I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuaGc.png)

I am looking for the direction to go to approach the issue and not asking for someone to do the coding for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The following should help populate the column you want to create:

```
SELECT ENROLMENT.AmountPaid,  IIf([ENROLMENT]![AmountPaid]>0,"Yes","No") AS Paid
FROM ENROLMENT;
```

Comment: I will work with that suggestion and see what kind of results I get. Thank you for your input, Charles_D.

Comment: I had a bit more time and this is more in keeping with your tables: 
  SELECT Enrollment.Enrollment_PK, tblCustomer.CustomerLastName, tblCustomer.CustomerFirstName, tblCustomer.Phone, Course.CourseNumber, Course.CourseDate, Course.Fee, Enrollment.Amount_Paid, IIf(([Course]![Fee]-[Enrollment]![Amount_Paid])>0,"Not Paid","Paid") AS Paid_Flag
FROM (Enrollment INNER JOIN tblCustomer ON Enrollment.Customer_FK = tblCustomer.Customer_PK) INNER JOIN Course ON Enrollment.Course_FK = Course.Course_PK;

Comment: Charles_D, In the text I am using I have not seen the construct using "IIf" with "!". I will have to delve into that further. I am particularly interested in knowing if the ">0" works for a column with CHAR (3) for its attributes. (That column is constrained to "Yes" or "No.")

Comment: Hi,  I created a sample query to test and all worked well.  The iif clause is the same as the if clause.  The expression with >0 is evaluated and the column populated with either a "Yes" or a "No" both of character type.